# How to chain completable futures

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I have three functions `updateFieldFromCollection1()`, `insertFromColletion1ToCollection2()` and `deleteFromCollection1()` now.

These calls aren't as such dependent on each other but when I want to chain them in *completableFuture* they have to run one after the other in the given order.

```
update-> insert -> delete
```

The calls don't return anything so i am using *runAsync* and *thenRun* methods of *completableFuture*. And have chained them accordingly. I am iterating on msgIds which is a list of strings.

```
msgIds.stream().forEach(msgId -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->  
 {updateFieldFromCollection1()}).thenRun(() -> 
 {insertFromColletion1ToCollection2()}).thenRun(() ->  
 {deleteFromCollection1()}));
```

The above code works (update-> insert -> delete are done) but throws exception like duplicateKey and bulkwrite. I am sure that the problem comes because another thread is starting before the previous thread completes its task. I want them to run asynchronously but I want to discipline the threads by avoiding conflicts.
I am not sure where I need to tweak the code.

Comment: can you add the exceptions with stack trace

Comment: Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: colllection2 index: _id_ dup key: { : "someID" }', details={ }}].  
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection:collection2 index: _id_ dup key: { : "someId" }

Comment: The code works smoothly without any exceptions when three functions are clubbed into single function. But i need to operate separately on them.

Comment: I think you can test it by using the methods supplyAsync and thenApply to get and log the info from each previous step

Comment: Have you tried with `thenRunAsync` instead of `thenRun`?

Comment: yeah i tried but got same errors

Answer (score 1):

```
msgIds.stream().forEach(msgId -> {
updateFieldFromCollection1();
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
 {insertFromColletion1ToCollection2()}).thenRun(() ->  
 {deleteFromCollection1()}));
```

The update had to be made outside completableFuture. Then it works like a charm :)